# PR estimation of a cross sectional study with a continuous variable possibly by Cox proportional hazard regression

Tags: r, cox-model, continuous-data, cross-section

I have a table of a simple cross sectional data:

```
     Outcome Predictor
  1:      1   1.9571444
  2:      1   6.2957907
  3:      1   0.5125633
  4:      1   3.9978328
  5:      1   1.2885436
 ---                   
158:      2   3.0989126
159:      2   0.8838995
160:      2   3.9801100
161:      2  -1.3533320
162:      2   5.5115921
```

and summary of the data:

```
Characteristic  N = 1621
Outcome 
1   119 (73%)
2   43 (27%)
Predictor   3.15 (1.49, 5.33)
1 n (%); Median (IQR)
```

I've read the following article:

Aluísio JD Barroscorresponding author1 and Vânia N Hirakata1, "Alternatives for logistic regression in cross-sectional studies: an empirical comparison of models that directly estimate the prevalence ratio"

doi: 10.1186/1471-2288-3-21 https://dx.doi.org/10.1186%2F1471-2288-3-21

These authors used "Cox regression with constant time at risk" to estimate prevalence ratio of the cross sectional data in question.

My question is if it is possible to use their strategy for the cross-sectional data with the continuous variable to obtain the correct PR estimate?

I would also appreciate an example of a R code to do this. My Ultimate goal is to be able to generate a graph with PR vs predictor.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted the first of author of the publication, Dr. Aluísio J D Barros, regarding the question that I posted.  He kindly answered my question and he suggested to use;

**Poisson regression with robust std errors**.

A following is a Stata code he shared with me;

```
poisson yourbinaryoutcome yourcontinuouspredictor, r irr
predict rr, ir
scatter rr yourcontinuouspredictor
```

Comment: Fix up the syntax, please.